# Quickest way to check only one of each instance?

Tags: java

For lack of a better title, I am looking for the best way to check this:

I have an arrow object. I also have objects that I want to code collision for, object1, object2, ... objectx, with objectx being the last object I am checking for.

In the collision system of the engine I am using, there is an x1 object, and an x2 object, which can vary for objects in a collision. For example if an arrow hits any object 1 through x, I don't know from the start if the arrow is x1 or x2, but it can be easily checked.

I want to write an if statement that is true if one object is an arrow, and the other is one of my many objects. This is what I have so far:

```
if ((x1Type.equals("arrow") || x2Type.equals("arrow")) && ((x1Type.equals("object1") || x1Type.equals("object2") || x1Type.equals("object3") || ... || x1Type.equals("objectx")) || 
                        x2Type.equals("object1") || x2Type.equals("object2") || x2Type.equals("object3") || ... || x2Type.equals("objectx")))
```

This code works, but I am pretty sure there is a better way to do it. And sorry for being kinda vague, this was a hard to state question.

Comment: This is a failure on the part of your underlying framework; if anything; and if it works then you probably can leave it alone, unless there is a significant problem with it.

Comment: @AnubianNoob I would definitely simplify this code.

Comment: @user2005938 what version of Java are you using?

Comment: Also, do you have access to the Object1, Object2, Object3... source code? Then you could make them all implement an interface, say Collidable that has no methods but can mark all the objects. Then you could say x2Type.equals("Collidable")

Comment: if you can - replace conditionals with polymorphism http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can access the type of your object from the objects themselves, what do you think about using a `Collection` (typically, a `Set`) to check whether the colliding object is supposed to be impacted by your arrow or not?

I'm suggesting something like this:

```
public static final String TYPENAME_ARROW = "arrow";
public static final Set<String> impactedTypes = new HashSet<String>() {
    {
        add("object1");
        add("object2");
        add("object3");
        add("objectx");
    }
};

public static void collide(final Object x1, final Object x2) {
    if (x1.getType().equals(ARROW_TYPE)) {
        if (impactedTypes.contains(x2.getType())) {
            // hit x2 with x1;
        }
    } else if (x2.getType().equals(ARROW_TYPE)) {
        if (impactedTypes.contains(x1.getType())) {
            // hit x1 with x2;
        }
    }  
}
```

I wanted to put this as a comment but well, that's too big. I might be completely wrong, in which case, please kindly let me know and I'll just delete my answer :)

Comment: Haha thanks, actually I would -1 for double bracket initialization but hey, I felt kinda lazy! And yes, I'm kind of an adept of `final` and `private` stuff in general :)